# Specify JRE/JDK when starting Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

Is there a way to tell Tomcat 7 the path to the JVM that must be used? For example:

```
startup --jvm /path/to/my/jvm
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu that is system-specific? I shall scour AskUbuntu as well....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A more flexible approach is to create a file named `setenv.bat` / `setenv.sh` (pick the right one for your platform) in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin` and set `JAVA_HOME` there. That way it only affects Tomcat, not anything else you are running. It also makes it easy to run multiple different Tomcat installations on different JVMs.

Comment: This is helpful. Is this documented on Tomcat's site? (As opposed to only knowing this by viewing the source files.)

Comment: See RUNNING.txt in the root of every Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add `JAVA_HOME` variable to `.bash_profile`
2. Add `path`/`classpath` entries
3. Export them

e.g.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib

export JAVA_HOME PATH CLASSPATH
```

Comment: Here is the Gist that I used in case someone else could need it https://gist.github.com/2599881