# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Jsp program.
it has built by netbeans 8.2 and jdk 1.8.
in windows when i run it on tomcat7, everything is ok. but when i run on tomcat7 in linux it throws following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

in linux `java -version is: openjdk version "1.8.0_141"`

and `javac -version: javac 1.8.0_141`

I don't know what is wrong.   jdk1.8 and openjdk 1.8 are not compatible?

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The version of java that is used by your tomcat (on linux) is not java 8 or is a different version of java 8 (not java 8 seems more likely).

Comment: Check the status page from tomcat to see wich java version it uses. http://localhost:8080/manager/status -> JVM Version

Comment: yes. thank u. tomcat is using java 7. how to change it to java 8?

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458109/specify-jre-jdk-when-starting-apache-tomcat-7